# Why doesn't my excel vba if/or statement work correctly?

Tags: excel, vba, logical-operators

I'm comparing values of numbers from 2 data sheets, and I've dropped the relevant data from both into their own arrays.  I need to find matching values to run other steps of analysis.

```
    For i = Lbound(Array1) to UBound(Array1)
        For j = LBound(Array2) to UBound(Array2)
            If (criteria for Array2) then
               variable = 11111
            Else
               variable = 22222
            End if
            If variable = Array1(i,1) Or variable = Array1(i,2) or variable = Array1(i,3) then
               more steps
            Else
               more steps
            End if
         next j
    next i
```

The first if statement sets the variable correctly, but the variable doesn't match any of the criteria. It doesn't go to the else like it should. Now I only know this because I walked through the code step by step. If I just F5 and run the thing, "Excel is not responding". I don't know what the hang up it. All of  my variables are declared and assigned a type, I'm not missing any closing statements. And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

What do I need to check for in my code?

EDIT

Sorry, but in this instance I'm not allowed to upload any code here. It's work related, NDA kind of stuff. Hence the pseudo code. What I need to show wouldn't be a big deal(at least I don't think it would), but I'm not risking it.

Comment: Are the values in Array1 stored as text?

Comment: This is not VBA '(criteria for Array2)'.  What did you intend here?

Comment: @ScottCraner Array(i,1) could be a number or empty. The other 2 are supposed to be Long, but I just double checked and the locals window says Double for both. My variable is a Long. If that's the issue, I don't understand why since everything is a number.

Comment: @freeflow It's a place holder, not my actual code. That part works fine.

Comment: It's very difficult to establish your problem with pseudocode. I suggest you update your post with actual code. Have you tried using ranges directly (i.e. no arrays). Following @Scott 's point, have you tried something like `variable = Val(Array1(i,1)) Or variable = Val(Array1(i,2)) ...`?

Comment: We should be able to reproduce your problem. That is not possible with what you have provided.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Ranges are very large and bogs down the machine, so arrays are more practical in this case. I have not tried 'Val(Array1(i,1))'. I will, but what is that supposed to do for me? I've only been coding (vba or anything) for a couple of months. Learn by doing approach.

Comment: Are you attempting to determine if two Doubles are equal? That is a recipe for failure.

Comment: FYI the "not responding" is probably due to the size of the Arrays.  You're doing a nested loop, so executing (size of A) * (size of B) iterations.  In the extreme, if both were from whole  columns that would be > 1,000,000,000,000 iterations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies.

The solution, as it turns out, has to do with a poorly named array(not me) and a simple typo(definitely me). I'm certain that would have been an easy solve for the good citizens of Stack Overflow if I would have been allowed to post actual code.

For what's it worth, I think it's dumb that I couldn't in this case. Thanks @ScottCraner and @SuperSymmertry for trying to be helpful even without much to go on.

Super, I'm still curious about Val. If you've got a minute, I would appreciate more knowledge on that. Anything from an actual person is better than Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Are you attempting to compare Doubles with your If statements?

Comment: Using `Val` was just an elimination strategy rather than a solution. Without knowing how you declared or populated your arrays there's always the possibility that you were actually comparing numeric values with `String`s. *Note: `Val("5.6")` evaluates the string `"5.6"` to the numeric value `5.6`*.